# Is there an GUI for Mercurial that makes my life really easy?

Tags: macos, mercurial

Can you recommend one over another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Windows and Linux (It also partially work on Mac, look at the comment of Nicholas Riley to this answer) there is [TortoiseHG](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) clone of the excelent [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

The great thing about theses two is that they are integrated in the shell (Windows Explorer or Nautilus). You see small icons over your files and folder that inform you about the status of your file in regards to the repository and you have a collection of commands/tools accessible from the context menu on theses files.

Comment: Note that you can also use TortoiseHg on the Mac, while it doesn't have any shell integration, you can launch it from the command line.  I find it preferable to Murky (and I say this as a contributor to Murky, unfortunately :-()

Comment: @barjak: Really? I did not knew that. Can it be integrated in Nautilus?

Comment: Looks like it can. That's great news.

Comment: there are a few differences between the windows and the linux version, but they have the same features. Both are perfectly usable. It is integrated in Nautilus, but sometimes the mercurial menu is missing when I am in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 6):

I like [Murky](http://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home).  There is another that's okay but not quite as good called [SourceTree](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/).

Answer (score 5):

There's also [MacHg](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/), which I was introduced to recently.

Comment: @pjacobs - If I am, then I must be writing code in my sleep under the name Jason Harris.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mercurial page for GUI tools and integrations to IDE: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/OtherTools

For Windows I use HgWin tool (http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgwin_news_eng.html), which provide a GUI for the most of mercurial commands. It is similar to hgtk, but uses mercurial command line client (hg.exe) as backend.